# How long after a US serviceman is killed would the family receive the 100K death benefit?

Tags: united-states, benefits, death

Under ordinary circumstances how soon after a serviceman's confirmed death would the family actually have the 100K to use for expenses?

(My understanding that this 100K is in addition to life insurance, the 100K is to cover travel and funeral expenses)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article on foxnews.com](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2013/10/10/senate-approves-bill-to-pay-military-death-benefits.html), the military typically pays the $100k death gratuity benefit within 3 days of a service member’s death.

If you do find yourself in this terrible situation, you will be assigned a casualty assistance officer that will help you with the process and answer any questions you have.

Comment: The article you've cited is from 2013. The ABC.com and Military.com reports for 2018 indicate that these benefits would NOT be paid DURING the shutdown, that in fact FisherHouse had agreed to fill the gap until casualty benefits are authorized.

Comment: Callous is not my intention, but (for example) when are funeral and transportation expenses required to be paid?  Of course I am assuming that  the military itself would be paying for embalming and funeral prep and as well as transportation of the remains to the family home - but I well could be very mistaken.

Comment: @BobE I am unsure of the current legislative/procedural status of this particular issue, so I have removed that sentence. Note that much of the reporting about this has a political agenda.